# Related tables problems with filtering/limiting data using markings

Tags: spotfire

[image: tableA]

[image: tableB]

I have created a relation between two tables based on column X. Table A contains 6 unique variables in column X, while table B only 4 of those.

In my visualization, i have one tree chart, based on column X from table A, which markings limits the results in the bar chart based on table B.

Problem is that when on the tree chart I select one of the variables that are available in table A but not in table B, bar chart still shows me a total number of records instead of the message "no data to show".

Edit: Bar chart options in "Data --> if no items are marked in the master visualization, show" should be marked with option "All data"

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: @ Karolina- Could you post a screenshot of the tables with sample data?

Comment: just did it, hopefully it can help

Answer (score 0):

@Karolina - I emulated your steps and the results are below.
Based on the screenshots posted, I have created Table A and Table B with some sample data. Table A has six unique values in 'Region' columns where as Table B has only 4.

[image: TableA_TableB]

**Step 1:** Created a relationship between these two tables with Region.

[image: TableA_B relation]

**Step 2:** Created a tree map on Table A and details visualization (Bar chart) on Table B

When I selected a region which is there is Table A but not in Table B, data didn't show up in Table B. Below is the screenshot.

[image: TableA_B_viz]

Comment: And what do you have ticked in the "Data --> if no items are marked in the master visualization, show"?With the option "empty visualization" you indeed get empty graph, but I have here "all data" and would like to keep it like this (due to the fact that the layout is more complicated than just these 2 graphs). I would like to have "all data" and get an info "all data have been filtered out" any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Message on white background - 'No data available'. If a 'Region' is selected in Tree map which is present in Table A but not in Table B, Bar chart shows empty visualization

Comment: yes correct. If "Message on white background" is selected you get the empty chart. I need to reeedit my question. Is it possible to have any kind of feedback info that the data are not available while having in "Data --> if no items are marked in the master visualization, show" option "All data"